# Getting process ID of a SHDocVw.InternetExplorer spawned IE8 process

Tags: .net, internet-explorer-8, mshtml, pid

I'm using [SHDocVw.InternetExplorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(VS.85).aspx) to launch IE in my code. In certain cases InternetExplorer.Quit() doesn't work. I have [tried several things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077003/debugging-shdocvw-internetexplorer-quit-not-closing-iexplore-exe-process) to make Quit work but without success. I'm now resorting to Process.Kill.

Now if a manually launched instance of IE8 is already running when SHDocVw.InternetExplorer is used to launch another one the new one gets created as a child process of the existing IE:

[image: SHDocVw.InternetExplorer spawned IE is a child of the existing IE]

The SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE is process id 996 on the screenshot, the manually launched one is 3388 plus its child 2876.

Now if I use [InternetExplorer.HWND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb268219(VS.85).aspx) to retrieve the window handle of my IE and then [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522(VS.85).aspx) to get the process ID I end up with 3388, the parent IE process ID when what I want is 996, the InternetExplorer.HWND launched IE process ID.

I'm not sure on which step it gets wrong.
*Should I be retrieving the HWND in a different way or the process ID? Or both?*

Thanks!

**Edit:** I've just tried sending `WM_CLOSE` to the HWND and it closed the parent IE. I suppose it  means I'm getting a wrong HWND?

**Edit:** It may be worth noting that only the manually launched IE is visible when I do the closing. Would this mean I'm getting the HWND of the only visible IE therefore?

Comment: You are probably getting confuzzled by the instance IE starts up to display content in a tab.  If the web page causes a crash then it won't take IE down with it.

Comment: @Hans, Good point! I understand IE8 uses separate process for each tab. The thing is the instance I launch with SHDocVw.InternetExplorer gets its parent window set to a Control in my app, so it ends up embedded as a child in that Control. It would probably just add a tab to the running IE if you don't change the parent window, I should try. This may mean I need a way to launch IE as a separate process instead. I doubt it is possible with SHDocVw.InternetExplorer though.

Comment: It's possible, google ObjectFromLResult.